# link to a paper by Ramanujan

Tags: gm.general-mathematics

Hi friends,

Does anybody know of a pdf version of the following paper ?

Ramanujan, S. “Modular Equations and Approximations to Pi.” Quart. J. Pure Appl. Math. 45, 350-372, 1913-1914.

It's impossible to find it!

Thanks for your help

Comment: I haven't got a copy but here is a link to a blogpost which discusses the paper extensively: http://paramanands.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/modular-equations-and-approximations-to-pi-part-1.html#.UZNQtkmTo6I

(You could maybe email the author of the blog to see if he has a copy.)

Answer (score 2):

visit http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram06.pdf. I got that paper. I think it is so what u asked

Answer (score 1):

It's freely available on Google Books

http://books.google.fr/books?id=oSioAM4wORMC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false

(on page 23).